# Loading animation in Google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have developed this http://weathermap.cloudcontrolled.com/ from where you can click on a place and get the current weather details in it. Everything is working properly but its **getting small delay after click on a place to show weather**. For that I would like to show a small **loading animation inside the infowindow** and after the weather data available it will show the weather in the same infowindow. How to do this. (this is pure html/js site, you can view source code by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Get an animated icon from http://www.ajaxload.info/, call it `ajaxicon.gif`

Change your `map` click event to :

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    //call function to create marker
         if (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            marker = null;
         }
    // why do you recreate the marker over and over ??
    marker = createMarker(event.latLng, 'name', '<img src="ajaxicon.gif">');

    getWeather(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng(),function (data) {
        infowindow.setContent("<b>"+data.list[0].name+"</b><br>"+data.list[0].weather[0].description+"<br><center><img src=http://www.openweathermap.com/img/w/"+data.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png></center>");
    });
});
```

1. create the marker, place animated ajax-icon in the infoWindow through your `createMarker` function
2. on success / callback, replace infowindow content with actual weather content

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the following

```
google.maps.event.addListener('click', showLoading);

function showLoading(event) {
  var contentString = '<img src="images/loading.gif">';

  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  getWeather(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng(),function (data) {
    contentString = "<b>"+data.list[0].name+"</b><br>"+data.list[0].weather[0].description+"<br><center><img src=http://www.openweathermap.com/img/w/"+data.list[0].weather[0].icon+".png></center>"
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  });

  infoWindow.open(map);
};
```

Comment: Please explain why it works (what's wrong in original code)